# Error #0 when trying to save file on iOS device

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

i just finished creating an iOS and Android application with Air ( SDK 18 )
I get an Error #0 ( sometimes - inconsistable ) when trying to save a preferences file.
The code is quite straightforward:

```
private static var _file:File=File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(CONFIGFILE);
private static function saveFile():void{
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    if(File.applicationStorageDirectory.spaceAvailable>1024){
            fileStream.open(_file, FileMode.WRITE);
            fileStream.writeUTFBytes(Base64.encrypt(JSON.stringify(ob),Strings.HASHSALT));
            fileStream.close();
    }else{
        showLowSpaceAlert()
    }
}
```

On Android eveything works fine and on iOS there are no issues 50% of the time ... 
Anyone know this bug? Thanks!

Comment: What's the free space on the iOs device ?

Comment: iOS 9 sez: 52,4 MB
Air sez: 197746688 byte

will try to see if things change, if I clear more space. 
( the prefs file i am trying to save is a  mere 52 byte )

Comment: Rats! I just freed up some space.
Now with applicationStorageDirectory.spaceAvailable = 379666432
there is no issue... is there a documentation about the minimum free space neccessary?

Comment: OPut of curisity where are the docs for `Base64.encrypt`? I'm wondering about he combination of Base64,encryption and writing to a file.

Comment: there are no docs ... :) wrote that myself based on https://code.google.com/p/gioo-dummy-sxps/source/browse/trunk/AddonsDesktop/src/be/boulevart/as3/security/Base64.as?spec=svn96&r=96

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to create a File object with a static variable, static objects are created during the app init time and timing issues are likely to appear. Your problem is due to your code logic.

The correct way is:

```
private static var _file:File;
```

then:

```
private static function saveFile():void
{
    if(!_file)
    {
        _file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(CONFIGFILE);
    }
    //etc ...
}
```

Comment: Hm, I tried this before, but it did not yield any differences.
Same Error happened with a SharedObject btw.

Error #2130: Unable to flush SharedObject
Seems the available space is the issue ...

Answer (score 0):

The question have been asked on [Adobe Forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1492705) and the OP tends to says that the issue is because the iOs device lakes of free space.

You should consider freeing a bit of memory on your device.

Comment: @zantafio something like removing useless stuff

Comment: yes, of cozrse. but is strange to ask the user to clean his device with 40mb of free space when wanting to save 50 bytes ...

Comment: I know but... This is the only solution I've got now. Maybe we should report it to Apple/Adobe?

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever gotten this error when a device it out of space.  You might try these calls...

```
    trace( File.applicationStorageDirectory.spaceAvailable );
    trace( File.cacheDirectory.spaceAvailable );
```

...to get how many bytes of space are available to you.  For example...

```
    var data:String = Base64.encrypt(JSON.stringify(ob),Strings.HASHSALT);
    if ( data.length > File.cacheDirectory.spaceAvailable )
    {
        trace( "NOT ENOUGH SPACE" );
    }
    else
    {
        trace( "OK TO SAVE" );
    }
```

Comment: thats what i said in an answer earlier:
applicationStorageDirectory.spaceAvailable gives me 197746688 bytes...
the prefs file is only 56 byte

Comment: Check out this bug report and see if it fits your symptoms: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4052562